# Inline folding in Vim

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, folding

Is it possible to do inline folding in Vim as IntelliJ [does](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-autofolding-behavior.html):

[image: IntelliJ inline folding]

In Vim, it is possible to customize the inline heading but what IntelliJ does is different: The line contains some normal, visible text and some hidden, folded text together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. You have to play with `&foldtext`, and may be you'll also have to write your own `&foldepxr` in order to fold how you want.

You can find an example in my (newly published) [VimFold4C](https://github.com/LucHermitte/VimFold4C). I merge function parameters, I indent folded text, and I remove template parameters and namespace depending on an option.

NB: I still have issues with fold boundaries detections, and I had to use dirty hack to speed up the fold detection.